# Disable or enable action in jqgrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jqgrid, webforms

I use jqgrid and custom action formatter in app. I create action when `loadComplete`.
I want disable/enable this action base on value of Col1 ,for example if value of col1 is true then visible of action  set to true....
How do it?

```
 grid.jqGrid({
    url: 'jqGridHandler.ashx',
    datatype: 'json',
    colNames: ['Action','Col1','col2'],
    colModel: [
        {
            name: 'act',
            width: ($.browser.webkit ? 25 : 25),
            align: 'center',
            sortable: false,
            formatter: 'actions',
            formatoptions: {
                keys: true,
                delbutton: false,
                editbutton: false
            }
        },
        { name: 'Col1', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true },
        { name: 'col2', width: 100, sortable: true, hidden: true }
    ],
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [5, 10, 20],
    recordpos: "left",
    toppager: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    scrollOffset: 1,
    jsonReader:
    {
        repeatitems: false,
    },
    gridview: true,
    loadComplete: function () {
        var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'act');
        $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
            .each(function () {
                $("<div>", {
                    title: "MyAction",
                    mouseover: function () {
                        $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    mouseout: function () {
                        $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                    },
                    click: function (e) {
                        alert("'Custom' button is clicked in the rowis=" +
                            $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id") + " !");
                    }
                }
                ).css({ "margin-right": "5px", "float": "left", "cursor": "pointer" })
                    .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-custom")
                    .append('<span class="ui-icon icon-archive"></span>')
                    .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
            });
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try to filter the collection and just do the right cells

```
var iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'act');
var iCol1 = getColumnIndexByName(grid, 'Col1'); 
$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
//  .each(function () {

  .filter(function (index) {
      true==$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol1 + 1) + ")").val();
}) {
```

Comment: Where i use filter?after find ?

Comment: Its not work may be i am wrong.  var data = $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")").filter(function(index) { $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol1  + 1) + ")").val() == 'True';});

Comment: I wrote the code by heart, unfortunately ruined. the function must surely return statement: return true==$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol1 + 1) + ")").val();

Comment: I wrote the code by heart, unfortunately ruined. the function must surely return statement: return true==$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol1 + 1) + ")").val(); In addition, you should check what you give back the $(this).find.(...).val() command, the in alert or on the console, whether it is good for comparison. If you have questions, or you can possibly make it a jsfiddle is, let me know!